# Subtracting values from 2 data frames by rows based on a shared string name in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, string-matching, subtraction

I want to subtract from two different dataframes. I have a data frame with information in it, and another that has a "reference point".

I have one data frame, DF1, that has this information.

| Name | Key | BCD12A | ACA1 | DEX2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X_1_group1 | test1234 | 10 | 10 | 8 |
| X_2_group1 | test4553 | 8 | 7 | 4 |
| X_2_group2 | test3341 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| X_2_group1 | test2142 | 5 | 6 | 8 |
| X_1_group2 | test4722 | 6 | 7 | 4 |

Using DF1, I want to subtract the values in a specific row to the row of DF2 (below), but based on a numerical match from the first column.

For example, based on DF2 below, I have a string in DF2$Name as X_1_group1. In DF1, the first row has that same string in the first column. Since the name matches, I will subtract the values in that row of DF1 from that row in DF2. Note that there may be more than one string in DF1 with the same name, so I want to be able to match the names that way.

| Name | Key | BCD12A | ACA1 | DEX2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X_1_group1 | X_1_group1_A | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| X_2_group1 | X_1_group1_B | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| X_1_group2 | X_1_group1_C | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| X_2_group2 | X_1_group1_D | 2 | 1 | 2 |

DF3 (Which is the goal) - The second column, through different will stay the same that matches DF1.

| Name | Key | BCD12A | ACA1 | DEX2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X_1_group1 | test1234 | 8 | 8 | 7 |
| X_2_group1 | test4553 | 7 | 4 | 3 |
| X_2_group2 | test3341 | 3 | 4 | 3 |
| X_2_group1 | test2142 | 4 | 3 | 7 |
| X_1_group2 | test4722 | 4 | 5 | 1 |

Any help on name matching with two data frames for a subtraction would be much appreciated. I also want to generalize this that there will be a lot more columns than in this example, so anything that would consider that portion would help a lot too! Thanks for any help!

```
# DF1
Name <- c("X_1_group1", "X_2_group1", "X_2_group2", "X_2_group1", "X1_group2")
Key <- c("test1234", "test4553", "test3341", "test2142", "test4722")
BCD12A <- c(10, 8, 5, 5, 6)
ACA1 <- c(10, 7, 5, 6, 7)
DEX2 <- c(8, 4, 5, 8, 4)
DF1 <- data.frame(Name, Key, BCD12A, ACA1, DEX2)

# DF2
Name <- c("X_1_group1", "X_2_group1", "X_1_group2", "X_2_group2")
Key <- c("X_1_group1_A", "X_1_group1_B", "X_1_group1_C", "X_1_group1_D")
BCD12A <- c(2, 1, 2, 2)
ACA1 <- c(2, 3, 2, 1)
DEX2 <- c(1, 1, 3, 2)
DF2 <- data.frame(Name, Key, BCD12A, ACA1, DEX2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use a join by 'Key' and subtract the corresponding numeric columns.  With `powerjoin`, we have the option to get the difference (`-`) where there are `conflict`ing names (common names)

```
library(powerjoin)
library(dplyr)
DF1 %>%
    power_left_join(DF2 %>% select(-Key), by = "Name", conflict = `-`)
```

-output

```
        Name      Key BCD12A ACA1 DEX2
1 X_1_group1 test1234      8    8    7
2 X_2_group1 test4553      7    4    3
3 X_2_group2 test3341      3    4    3
4 X_2_group1 test2142      4    3    7
5 X_1_group2 test4722      4    5    1
```

---

Or using `data.table` join

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- names(DF1)[3:5]
nm2 <- paste0("i.", nm1)
setDT(DF1)[DF2, (nm1) := Map(`-`, mget(nm1), mget(nm2)), on = .(Name)]
```

Comment: If used in a large data set, an error appears saying: Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?). Is there a way to make the code more efficient to run large files (thousands of columns) or is that more of a computer issue?

Comment: @dkcongo `data.table` method should be efficient compared to the first method, but still if you have memory issues, you may have to try using some `lazy` method to do the join before collecting the data as in `polars` in python or may have to subset the data to include only the relevant columns before joining